# Problem with creating a PPI network in Cytoscape using STRING database version 12. Cytoscape downloads data STRING v.11.5

Tags: string, cytoscape

When creating the PPI network, cytoscape retrieves data from the 11.5 version of the string database. There is now a new version 12. How to create a network with this data? I need to perform further analyses on the latest version of PPI STRING.

#cytoscape #String12 #string

I have updated Cytoscape to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other forums, the stringApp is being updated to use STRING v12, but it's not quite ready yet.  We'll make an announcement as soon as it's released.

In the meantime, you could Export the network using the "...as short tabular text output" option and load that into Cytoscape using the File->Import->Network from File..."